Windows 10 won't boot either from HDD or live USB. Ubuntu boots fine. How do I diagnose the issue?
I have an Acer Aspire 3 A315-21G-962Y that refuses to boot into anything Windows.
When I attempt to start the laptop, the OEM logo shows up and then it reboots after a few seconds. This mostly goes on and on in a loop. Sometimes, after the logo is shown, it won't reboot but instead it freezes, and the screen gets filled with garbage.
Things I tried

Using media creation tool from windows to make a bootable USB and attempt to reinstall Windows.
I get the same behavior as when it attempts to boot from the HDD. The moment it starts to boot from the USB, it restarts.
Used a different USB stick.
Reset BIOS to default.
Disabled all virtualization and security options in the BIOS.
Replaced the RAM sticks. No difference.
I checked the USB stick on another machine, and it worked just fine so the USB isn't at fault.
Removed the HDD from the faulty laptop, placed it in another machine and it boots fine.
Did a clean Windows install on the HDD on the other machine just in case. When I placed it back in the laptop, the same boot loop.
Tried using a different SSD with the laptop, which is known to work. Same boot loop.
With the HDD on another machine, configured Windows to boot into minimal Safe Mode, enabled boot log and base video, disabled reboot on error.

At this point, when I placed it back in the laptop and tried booting, I stopped getting the boot loop but instead got an error message from boot manager

Trying to use "ESC" to enter recovery leads to the computer rebooting.
I was hoping that after I enabled "Boot log", I would get some info on what is going on but the ntbootlog.txt doesn't get written.
The last thing I tried is a Lubuntu live USB to see if I can get some diagnostics... And whaddaya know, the thing boots just fine. Installed Lubuntu, did some stress testing, surfed the web. All is well.
Tried booting from a Windows USB again, and I still get the boot loops.
I suspect the issue is with a faulty driver or faulty device that Windows may be attempting to use when it boots and fails. A device that Lubuntu isn't using.
How can I diagnose this and get the thing running Windows 10 again?
Edit: After playing with it on Lubuntu for a while, I noticed the screen would show random glitches. I then noticed this only happens when I run tasks with the discrete GPU. When running them with the integrated GPU only, all is well. Even so, I could never get it to downright crash.
Is it possible that the discrete GPU is failing and causing Windows to crash when booting? How can I diagnose and confirm this?

According to that link and based on my observations, the issue seems to happen before or during the bootloader phase. The instructions on the link require me to use a Windows Installation Media. As I said in the question, attempting to boot the installation media exhibits the same behavior.

According to https://www.emag.ro/laptop-acer-aspire-a315-21g-962y-amd-a9-9420-4gb-ddr4-hdd-500gb-amd-radeon-520-2gb-linux-122252/pd/DFJM90BBM/: Acer Aspire A315-21G comes with Linux installed. It might not be able to run Windows 10. You could try Windows XP, which is referenced elsewhere, but I'd stick with Linux, which is being kept up-to-date. In any event, Win 10 loses support in a year or so, and it's unlikely that PC could run Win 11, if it can't run 10.

It had run windows 7 or 8 (can't remember) for several years. Then it was upgraded to 10 and ran that for a good while too. But I guess I could try XP / 7 again. Not much else I can try it seems. Also, see my edit.
